# React functional component communication

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a react webapp that requires a parent component call a function in the child component when a state changes. Something like this:

```
function Parent() {
  const [var,setVar] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    //something to call doSomething()
  },[var])

  return <div> <Child /> </div>
}

function Child() {
   const [data,setData] - useState([]);
   doSomething() {
     fetch('/path/').then((resp) => {
       setData(resp.data)
     }
   }

   return <div> Child </div>
}
```

This is actually my first time using react so sorry if this is a stupid question. I looked into it and it doesn't seem like contexts are the best to use for this case so I was wondering if there was an easier way to call "doSomething()". Thank you.

I am using the child in 2 places in my application. That is why I want to do this.

Comment: Will the function to be executed change something on the child? Could you give an example of that function? I think that the answer depends on that

Comment: why do you want to call the function from the parent?

Comment: I think a little more context would be appropriate, as it stands right now you would not normally do something like this.

Comment: Yes the "doSomething" function will make an API call and set a variable in Child

Comment: The way you set it up, even if you call `doSomething`, its not going to change the Child view. I recommend you create a codesandbox sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way for you to execute `doSomething` in a child is, if you pass in the dependent value that affects the function execution i.e. your parent component executes the function when `var` changes.

> Pass in the `var` as prop to your child component and move the effect from parent to child component.

This would mean if something in parent component changes (in this case `var` changes), a function in child component gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You also can do this through the use of callbacks. Pass in a callback to the child component, then pass `doSomething` into said callback. You then have access to the function.

```
function Parent() {
    const [var,setVar] = useState();

    // State to contain the child's function
    const [doSomething, setDoSomething] = useState()

    // Callback to receive the child's function
    const handleDoSomething = doSomething => setDoSomething(doSomething)

    useEffect(() => {
        doSomething()
    },[var, doSomething])

    // Pass the callback to Child
    return <div> <Child getDoSomething={ handleDoSomething } /> </div>
}

function Child({ getDoSomething }) {
    doSomething() {return "something"}

    // Pass doSomething into the callback
    getDoSomething(doSomething)

    return <div> Child </div>
}
```